# How to wait for a result with multiple JavaFX Windows in a static function?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, java-threads

My question is, how I can easily wait on the result of a window in witch the user is entering some informations?

Basic Problem:

```
public static char[] getPassword(String message) {
        run = true;
        showWindow(message);   // JFrame or FX-Window

        /* DOES NOT WAIT HERE !!! */

        // Working on the insert data of "password1"
        if (pwMatches()) {
            return password1;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

https://pastebin.com/06itDs1X - only pseudo code, untested! Real code is to complex.

The task:

- FX-Window is running (main stage)
- User should enter a new password in a stage (pw stage)
- after entering the password, the main stage should go on

The Problem:

- main stage does not wait, goes on before password is entered
- simple demo code: https://pastebin.com/560v1wmd

results

```
main 1
main 2
s1
s2
```

The solutions:

- 1:  https:// pastebin.com/kCAep2gr
- 2:  https:// pastebin.com/MSJ0kHfU

results the correct order

```
main 1
s1
s2
main 2
```

Problem:

- Solution 1 needs much modifications in the code.

  - I used this, but would ask for a better solution or is this the best?
- Solution 2 does not work for JavaFX (Thread is no FX-Thread)

## Question:

Any easy solution for JavaFX or is Solution 1 the best?

Comment: Why not start with your password `Stage`?

Comment: Are you using `FXML` or pure code?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson:
_ First Question: _
Is for password changes, simply calling it somewhere in the code. Yes, it would be a solution to reorder all classes and switching beween stages. Currently it is parallel, the password frame is started addionally.

_ Secound Question: _


The gui elements are created with a tool .fxml, the controller classes are self written .java.

Comment: The idea in the answer I posted is the same. When you load your `FXML` file make sure you set `initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);`

Comment: Can you create and post a [MCVE] (i.e. a new, simple, but complete, project that does nothing more than is needed to demonstrate the problem)? From your description it should be possible to do that in no more than a few dozen lines of code, at most.

Comment: @James_D Here is a sample code: 
https://mega.nz/#!4SwhhLqI!yViuRRRLTwnZbxyFGiGARoi7VurkKPht7IaKFkeAnK0
 at MiniLoader.java line 25 you can switch to working lamda version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample app halts interactions on the Main Stage until a password is entered. The password is `password`.  **Note: `passwordStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);//This is important if you don't want the user to interact with other windows`**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication22 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Stage passwordStage = getPasswordStage();
                passwordStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);//This is important if you don't want the user to interact with other windows
                passwordStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
                passwordStage.showAndWait();
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(new StackPane(new Label("Main Center")));
        root.setTop(new StackPane(new Label("Main Screen")));
        root.setRight(new StackPane(new Label("Main Right")));
        root.setLeft(new StackPane(new Label("Main Left")));
        root.setBottom(new StackPane(btn));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Stage getPasswordStage()
    {
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Enter password here");

        Button button = new Button("login");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(textField.getText().equals("password"))
            {
                stage.close();
            }
        });


        VBox vbox = new VBox(new StackPane(textField), new StackPane(button));
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(vbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane,300, 200);

        stage.setTitle("Login Screen");
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        return stage;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
After `passwordStage.showAndWait();` the insert password can used for whatever you want.

Comment: Trying to combine JavaFX and no FX seems a bad solution: 
https://mega.nz/#!lK5jUDrT!fu7rMVUstG_NeLtJjEKALbhEl3plnMBv4_u-lK5hH7Y
 I can not get Java to switch [no fx] -> [fx] -> [no fx] -> [fx] -> [no fx]. FX can started only once and after exit it seems to be imposible to restart it.

Comment: So use no FX, only FX once or write it completly in FX. Calling a static method for nice looking ui multiple times seems imposible (was my question)

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by `So use no Fx`?

Comment: I mean: Take Swing, AWT or no gui with "no fx". So create a program that:

Comment: 1: is written in JavaFX

Comment: or 2: a program without gui but using JavaFX only one time to get the inputs by the user

Comment: or 3: write the program in AWT or Swing

Comment: I would write the program using `JavaFX`.

Comment: **I agree.** Only on some linux systems openjdk without `JavaFX` is used.